# Having a problem with my transform: translate property

Tags: javascript, css, ejs

I'm trying to make an icon appear when my image is hovered over.  I set the transform: translate property to start at 0, but when the page loads it's still visible for a split second.  I was expecting it only to be visible when hovered over.  Does anyone know what's going on?

```
 <div class="item green col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <a href="/blog/<%= blog._id %>"><img src="<%=blog.source%>" class="index_image" alt="Blog post with image."></a>
      <a style="color:black" href="/blog/<%= blog._id %>"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></a>
 </div>
```

```
div.item:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: grayscale(50%)
  }
div.item i {
    transform: translate(-600%, -150%) scale(0);
    transition: transform 300ms 0ms cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045);
  }

div.item:hover i {
    transform: translate(-600%, -150%) scale(2.5);
    transition: transform 300ms 100ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  }
div.item * {
   transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  }
```

I've included some relevant code, but can certainly provide more if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not sure if you needed those extra transformations, it can be solved with simple opacity.

```css
.index_image {
  width: 200px;
}

div.item {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.item:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: grayscale(50%)
}

div.item i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.item:hover i {
  opacity: 1;
}

div.item * {
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="item green col-lg-3 col-md-6">
  <a href="/blog/"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1003914/pexels-photo-1003914.jpeg" class="index_image" alt="Blog post with image."></a>
  <a style="color:black" href="/blog/"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I can't believe I didn't think of that!